# Imagem não aparece - php

Tags: php, mysql, imagem

Estou tentando trazer a imagem do banco Mysql para uma página PHP porém não aparece.

Segue o código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") 
or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados");      
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($conexao,"mentoria"); 
$campos = array(".", "-");      


$cpf = str_replace($campos,"",$_POST["inputCPF"]);

$consulta_jovens = "SELECT jfoto,jnome,jfaixaetaria,jescolaridade,jhobby,jcomida,jmusica,jesporte,jtime,jcaracteristica,janimal,jlivro,jsonho, ((CASE WHEN jovem.jfaixaetaria = mentor.mfaixaetaria THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jescolaridade = mentor.mescolaridade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jhobby = mentor.mhobby THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcomida = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jmusica = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jesporte = mentor.mesporte THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jtime = mentor.mtime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcaracteristica = mentor.mcaracteristica THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.janimal = mentor.manimal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jlivro = mentor.mlivro THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jsonho = mentor.msonho THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS qtdCaracteristicasIguais FROM jovem INNER JOIN mentor ON jovem.jcidade = mentor.mcidade AND jovem.jestado = mentor.mestado WHERE mentor.mcidade = jovem.jcidade AND mentor.mestado   = jovem.jestado AND mentor.CPF ='$cpf' ORDER BY qtdCaracteristicasIguais DESC LIMIT 2";

$string_sql = "SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE CPF='$cpf'";  



$result= mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql); 

$resultadojovens = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta_jovens);

$dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    


$nome = $dado['mnome'];     


if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao)){ 
    echo "<p><h2>Olá, $nome! <br><br> Escolha o seu mentorando abaixo:</h2></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p></p>";
    while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){

    echo '<header ("content-type: image/jpg")>'.'<b>Foto: </b>'.'<img src='.$aluno['jfoto'].'>'."<br />" .'<b>Nome: </b>'.$aluno['jnome']."<br />".'<b>Faixa Etária: </b> '.$aluno['jfaixaetaria']."<br />".'<b>Escolaridade: </b> '.$aluno['jescolaridade']."<br />" .'<b>Hobby: </b>'.$aluno['jhobby']."<br />".'<b>Comida: </b>'.$aluno['jcomida']."<br />".'<b>Estilo Musical: </b>'.$aluno['jmusica']."<br />" .'<b>Esporte: </b>'.$aluno['jesporte']."<br />".'<b>Time de Futebol:</b> '.$aluno['jtime']."<br />".'<b>Caracteristica:</b> '.$aluno['jcaracteristica']."<br />" .'<b>Animal favorito: </b>'.$aluno['janimal']."<br />".'<b>Livro: </b>'.$aluno['jlivro']."<br />".'<b>Sonho: </b>'.$aluno['jsonho']."<br /> <br />" ;
}

} else {
    echo mysqli_errno($conexao) . ": " . mysqli_error($conexao) . "\n";
}

mysqli_close($conexao); 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O while do aluno retorna os dados corretamente? Se sim, o caminho da imagem esta preenchido no banco? Se sim, o caminho do link está completo/correto? Acredito que nao precisa da tag header image aí no echo...

Comment: Olá, Darlei. O while retorna o valor correto... não tenho caminho da imagem, só salvei direto na tabela.

Comment: Se voce nao salvou o caminho todo da imagem, deverá definir o caminho quando der o echo no src da imagem, voce trabalha com um arquivo de config?

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo .php que eu pego as informações da página e jogo no BD.

Comment: Esse header ai no meio do HTML não faz o mínimo sentido, tem outros problemas no código também. Tente fazer um [MCVE] sem esses erros que fica mais simples de ajudar. O primeiro teste seria você acessar a imagem diretamente, ou ao menos fazer uma página mais simples, que mostre só o link direto pra imagem para você clicar. Uma vez funcionando o link, aí você passa ele para o `src`